# How to Highlight the active Chrome Window- Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I usually have multiple chrome windows open (3 or 4) on my monitor.

Something like the below. Often, I get lost on knowing which my active window is.

- It hurts the most when you accidentally close a tab (when you are in the middle of writing some draft that doesn't have auto-save)

I do ctrl+tab to figure out which is my active window.

[image]

Wondering if there is some theme or extension that I can install to fix this.

Edit: This on Mac

Comment: The active window on Mac always has the colored-in "stoplights" at the top left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to make windows highlight active window with a different title bar color. First right click on any empty portion of desktop and click personalization. Then click Colors and select an accent colour. Now Only choose Shiw color on title bars. Now open the registry editor as Administrator. Now navigate to the key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM` and create a Dword value named `AccentColorInactive` and set value as FFB16300. Now the active window will have your chosen color from personalization settings and other windows will have default color.

For MacOS you can download Honer (https://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Honer.shtml) and it will show a red border around the active window and you will have no problem to understand.

Comment: I am on Mac. So I can't leverage Registry Keys

Comment: You should tag with the OS where you are in. I was thinking you are in windows 10. Without tags we cannot understand.

Comment: Please see the edit for MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Wasif's answer works for windows, to easily set the border color for non active windows you can also use winaero tweaker in appearance settings > non active window

Comment: Hi, this site does not run like a forum and this is not an answer so it will probably be deleted.  Thanking is done by voting up.